# Opencv Animation Rotation of object using rotation matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, animation, linear-algebra

The project I am working on is about an animation of a car that travels on a grid using x y z coordinates.

The rotation around the z axis was done with a simple rotation matrix using the angle, more accurately atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1), the rotation of the car when taking corners is done but now i need the car to rotate when going up on the z axis and when going down, simulating a slope like a real car would do.

So the problem is that I need 2 rotations in a single matrix, one for steering and one for "climbing" and "going down" a slope. I can't seem to find a good rotation matrix or calculate the right angle for that incline/decline.

Any ideas?

Comment: I agree, the angle is the pitch one, how do i find that axis ? I tried something with an arbitrary axis but it's really math intensive, and some use of quaternions.
http://reference.mrpt.org/devel/CPose3D.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need lerp and quaternions here, else rotation will look not natural.

You can check simple example here: [example](https://sites.google.com/site/threejstuts/home/slerp)
BTW, [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00153.html) have quaternion math.

Comment: Thanks, that GLM library was a life saver. I managed to figure it out with your links.